# Locating Selenium Safardriver Logs in OSX

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

Has anyone ever used the Webdriver logs from Safaridriver in OSX? I ask, as using the below Safaridriver configuration, I don't see the logs in the specified directory, or `/User/${USER}`, `/tmp`, or `/var/log`.

```
SafariDriverService svc = new SafariDriverService.Builder()
    .withLogFile(new File("/tmp/safaridriver.log"))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .build();
new SafariDriver(svc, options);
```

Does anyone know where ([Apple's bundled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari)) Safaridriver writes logs?

I also tried, using `RemoteWebDriver`

```
SafariDriverService service = new SafariDriverService.Builder()
    .withLogFile(new File("/tmp/safaridriver.log"))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .build();

RemoteWebDriver.builder()
    .withDriverService(service)
    .url(webDriverUrl)
    .addAlternative(options)
    .build();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setCapability("safari:diagnose", true);
```

This will create logs in `~/Library/Logs/com.apple.WebDriver/`

Some hints can also be found [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/web-platform/running-tests/safari.html)